# Capture window content to texture

Tags: c++, dll, window, directx, textures

let me first specify my development essentials. I am writing an Windows DLL. The programming language i do focus on is C/C++. Asm blocks are possible aswell when required for my task. Maybe even a driver, but i do not have any experience with them at all.
The DLL is being injected into a host process. That's always a Directx environment. Either Dx9, Dx10 or Dx11 and may run in fullscreen or windowed mode.
The method should support windows xp up to windows 7 and is being compiled in x86 only.

The goal is to come up with a function taking a screenshot of a given process-window. The screenshot is never being taken from the host process itself. Its always another process! The window may contain directx or gdi32 content. Maybe other contents are possible i do not think of at the moment (windows forms comes to my mind. i am not sure how that is being rendered internally). The windows may be minimized.

That screenshot needs to be accessable/convertable to an directx texture such as Texture2D, depending on the Directx environment i am working in. Saving the screenshot as an png/bmp is enough thoe, as i do know how to create such a texture from memory.

I've already tried the oldstyle BitBlt way, that didnt work on minimized applications thoe. The minimized applications are being drawn, when i send WM_PAINT messages to the targeting window. That aint a solution for me, as i also need to keep up with directx applications which doesnt react to such messages.

Maybe i need to hook each single DirectX window to accomblish my task, to access the backbuffer directly, i do hope for some better methods anyways.

For the reason that i do take a lot of screenshots from multiple windows, i would like to implement a fast method, which isnt such a cpu bogus. Copying from VideoRAM may be a bad way to go when having such performance needs.

I do hope for some ideas, maybe code samples as i am not familar with all the possibilities i could go for. I've looked at some windows thumbnail api, but that didnt support xp from what i could read.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: I also posted a similar topic on gamedev. I want to supply this topic with a question one guy dropped in:

Comment: At least some of what you require simply isn't possible in a generic way. For example many programs will detect that they are minimized and deliberately avoid doing any rendering or other significant processing until they are restored. Why do you want to be able to screen capture minimized apps? What is this program you're trying to create?

Comment: I want to actually create a dll which is being injected into every DX based game. From there the user can select through his opened processes. The selected once are being "captured" and written to some bitmap texture which i can than load as a picture into the dx based host game. The user could use icq, msn or his browser inside of the game than, without the program supporting that at all. Kinda like xfire, but tousand times better in my opinion.
Nice gimmics like to alphablend the picture out, lock it to some point at the screen, resize it to his likings is optional.

Comment: when the user clicks on the the windows, i am actually dispatching the messages to the original window, so it behaives as it would if i would have the real window, not just a texture.